# Probability given a mean and standard deviation of a random variable

Tags: probability

The number of transactions handled by a bank teller in a day is a random variable with a mean of 80 and standard deviation of 5.

What can be said that the teller will handle at least 400 transactions in a day?

What can be said about the probability that the teller will handle between 70 and 90 transactions in a day?

Comment: Read about the _Markov_ inequality which says that the probability that a nonnegative random variable $X$ takes on values $\alpha$ or larger is bounded above by $\mu/\alpha$ where $\mu$ is the mean of $X$. Similarly, read about the _Chebyshev_ inequality which bounds the probability that $X$ differs from its mean $\mu$ by $\alpha$ or more in terms of the standard deviation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that the teller will handle at least 400 transactions in a day is the following.
$$P(|X| \ge 400) \le \frac{80}{400} = \frac{1}{5}$$

The probability that the teller will handle between 70 and 90 transactions in a day is the following.
$$P(70 < X < 90) \ge 1-\frac{5^2}{100} = \frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You are asked what can be said about $P\{70 \leq Y \leq 90\} = P\{|Y-80|\leq 10\}$ or perhaps $P\{70 < Y < 90\} = P\{|Y-80| < 10\}$ depending on how you want to interpret the phrase "between $70$ and $90$". You have correctly bounded $P\{|Y-80|\geq 10\}$. Now turn the inequality around to get a _lower_ bound on the probability _requested_ in the problem

Comment: @DilipSarwate, can I assume the distribution is symmetric since the mean is 80?

Comment: No, if you assume a symmetric distribution, then since the teller cannot handle a negative number of transactions, the maximum number of transactions is restricted to be $160$ or less. You might want to give some thought to the fact that an $8$ hour work day has $480$ minutes (not considering lunch break, coffee break, etc) and so a teller who handles $400$ transactions in a day is processing them at an average rate of one a minute: highly unlikely!

Comment: I have deleted my earlier comments since you have fixed your answer and so they are no longer applicable.

Comment: $P(70<X<90)=1-P(|X-80|\geq 10)$ and Chebyshev's inequality says that for a random variable of mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, $$P(|X-\mu| \geq \alpha)= \frac{\sigma^2}{\alpha^2}.$$ Here $\mu=80$, $\sigma=5$ is given, and so $$P(|X-80|\geq 10) \leq \frac{5^2}{10^2} = \frac{1}{4}$$ and so $$P(70<X < 90) \geq \frac{3}{4}.$$

Comment: $90+60 = 2*80$  Try again. My calculator says that $90+60=2*75$.

Answer (score 0):

the probability that the teller will handle at least 400 transactions per day is close to 0,
Im 95% confident that the teller will handle between 70 to 90 transactions in a day.

Comment: Why are you fractionally confident that the teller will handle between 70 and 90 transactions a day? How can you be sure that the probability of handling at least 400 transactions is close to 0?  Please explain.

Comment: @DilipSarwate sorry, i take that back. I think i had assumed the distribution to be normal...

Comment: @DilipSarwate had the distribution been normal, i'd have been right?